# Directional Antenna in NS-2.34 or NS-2.35

Tags: ns2

I would like to know if ns-allinone-2.34 or ns-allinone-2.35 provides support for Directional Antenna?

Regards, 
Parham.

Comment: No they dont have. You have to create the antenna by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Omni Antenna is a default antenna in ns2..

Directional type antenna is not available in ns2 . You can add directional antenna manually.